# weight_quant/min, max restored in the check point are different with the actual min/max of the weight

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm doing some work with tensorflow object detection API. When I get the checkpoint (with quantization), I found that the weight_quant/min and the weight_quant/max are different with the actual min/max of the weight. Since I want to transfer the model to pytorch, it makes me confused to handle the min/max value in tf model and pytorch model.

My environment is tf1.9 with object detection API, ubuntu 16.04. I trained a mobilenet v1 model, and checked some weights in the model, here is an example:

> ('FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/weights_quant/min:0',
>   -3.2073412) ('FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/weights_quant/max:0',
>   5.7885404)
>
> ('FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/depthwise_weights:0',

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdfoa.png)

> ('actual min and max: ', -2.3553603, 2.1638136)

As shown above, the actual min/max value in 'FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_1_depthwise/depthwise_weights:0' tensor is -2.3553603 and 2.1638136, while the weights_quant/min and weights_quant/max value are different.

I tried assign the actual min/max value to weights_quant/min and weights_quant/max, but the result model is failed to detect any object.

So is there some other operation in recording the min/max value? How the recorded min/max work in inference?

Answer (score 0):

Got it....
The weight_quant/min and weight_quant/max value are calculated from a conv layer that has merged the corresponding BN layer.